# Refreshing a checkbox list in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I have an ordered checkbox list where I want to be able to change the order. The list is defined as:

```
 <fieldset id="myList" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind='foreach : Articles'>
                <legend></legend>
                <input data-theme="c" type="checkbox" data-role="controlgroup" data-bind="attr: { 'data-id': Id(), name: 'checkbox-' + Id(), id: 'checkbox-' + Id() }" />
                <label data-theme="c" data-bind="text: Name(), attr: { for: 'checkbox-' + Id() }"></label>
 </fieldset>
```

When the order in the articles property on my view model changes i want to refresh the checkbox list UI. Any ideas of how I can do that? I have tried .controlgroup('refresh',true) with no luck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: @ScottR i made a cusom mobileForeach bindinghandler as described here http://markmail.org/message/yipmzzwkqtflfqd3

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox jQM Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/methods.html

Try

```
.checkboxradio("refresh");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is taken straight from the documentation for jquery mobile:

Refreshing form elements
In jQuery Mobile, some enhanced form controls are simply styled (inputs), but others are custom controls (selects, sliders) built from, and kept in sync with, the native control. To programmatically update a form control with JavaScript, first manipulate the native control, then use the refresh method to tell the enhanced control to update itself to match the new state. Here are some examples of how to update common form controls, then call the refresh method:

```
              Checkboxes:
              $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");

              Radios:

              $("input[type='radio']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
               Selects:

              var myselect = $("#selectfoo");
              myselect[0].selectedIndex = 3;
              myselect.selectmenu("refresh")
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps at all:

I added this over to JQM forums a bit ago. It's a little bit more complete CSS to get better control of items. This is not found in the normal documentation.

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/css-code-to-help-control-entire-button-in-a-jquery-mobile-theme